# What super class to choose when creating a network handler class in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, network-programming

I'm currently creating a iOS 5 iPad app where there will be heavy network usage on a local domain, querying and fetching data, uploading and more.

So I'm thinking of creating a network handler that would take care of all these functionalities. Now in iOS/objective-c when you create a class you are really creating a interface of super classes (`NSObject`, `UIViewController` etc) and my question is which one would you use? `NSURLProtocol`?

I'm really new to iOS/Objective-c programming so I'm looking towards getting best practice tips from those more experienced in doing something similar to what I'm trying to do.

All advice would be appreciated.

-MrDresden

Comment: `NSViewController` is not part of iOS. I think you mean `UIViewController`.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry my bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating a network manager that abstracts all the dirty work, you should make it a subclass of `NSObject`, simply. All the work will be done by local instances of `NSURLConnection` (though I advise you to use some higher-level framework like AFNetwork which is very good).